# Removing bi-directional unique rows from text file

Tags: apache-spark, duplicates, graphstream

I have a text file as follows:

```
1    3
2    5
3    6
4    5
5    4
6    1
7    2
```

The above file represents the edges in an undirected graph. I want to remove the duplicate edges in the graph. In the above given example I want to remove  either `4,5 or 5,4` as they represent the same edge in graph and hence causes duplication. I am trying to visualize the graph from the file using `Graphstream` using the `GraphX` library in Apache Spark. But due to  the presence of duplicate nodes as explained above it gives an error as follows

```
org.graphstream.graph.EdgeRejectedException: Edge 4[5--4] was rejected by node 5
```

What would be the best way to remove such duplicates from the text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `convertToCanonicalEdges` method from `GraphOps`. It

- *Converts bi-directional edges into uni-directional*.
- *Rewrites the vertex ids of edges so that srcIds are smaller than dstIds, and merges the duplicated edges*.

In your case:

```scala
val graph = Graph.fromEdgeTuples(sc.parallelize(
  Seq((1, 3), (2, 5), (3, 6), (4, 5), (5, 4), (6, 1), (7, 2))), -1)

graph.convertToCanonicalEdges().edges.collect.foreach(println)
```

with result:

```
Edge(3,6,1)
Edge(1,6,1)
Edge(1,3,1)
Edge(2,5,1)
Edge(2,7,1)
Edge(4,5,1)
```